# Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(url: string) => string'.ts(2322)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-component

I have this material ui copyright component:

```
export default function Copyright(link: string, text: string) {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
      {'Copyright © '}
      <Link color="inherit" href={link}>
        {text}
      </Link>{' '}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {'.'}
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

If I try to use it like this, I don't get any errors:

```
{Copyright('https://hello.com', 'HELLO')}
```

However, if I try to use it like this:

```
<Copyright link={'https://hello.com'} text={'hello'}></Copyright>
```

I get this error on link even though I have not specified any 'url' anywhere else:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(url: string) => string'.ts(2322)
```

How can I use this component with the second method? A similar question suggested to use casting but in my case, there can be multiple links with which I want to call the component in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use

```
<Copyright link={"https://hello.com"} text={"hello"} />
```

You need to define the props type like this

```
props: { link: string; text: string }
```

Usage:

```
function Copyright(props: { link: string; text: string }) {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
      {"Copyright © "}
      <Link color="inherit" href={props.link}>
        {props.text}
      </Link>{" "}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {"."}
    </Typography>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit stupefied-jackson-r8tst]

Comment: Laugh on me, I don't care because I am not a web developer. But I got to learn to use props without a type from this answer. All these days I have been using a type for each function to have multiple props. Thanks!